# RSpec Rails NoMethodError: undefined method `password=' for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have run the tests and it doesn't seem that the user get created by a Factory Girl. Here's what I got:

reports_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ReportsController do
  let(:user) { create :user }

  before { sign_in user }

  describe 'GET #subjects' do
    subject { get :subjects }

    it_behaves_like 'template rendering action', :subjects
  end
end
```

factories/users.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email { Faker::Internet.safe_email }
    password { Faker::Internet.password }
  end
end
```

And when I run the test I get this error:

```
ReportsController
  GET #subjects
    behaves like template rendering action
      example at ./spec/support/shared/template_rendering_action.rb:2 (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) ReportsController GET #subjects behaves like template rendering action 
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `password=' for #<User:0x000000063abd20>
     Shared Example Group: "template rendering action" called from ./spec/controllers/reports_controller_spec.rb:11
...
```

I do not understand why it doesn't work. Anyone could point me to the mistake? Thanks.

Edit: I'm using devise.

Comment: It looks like FactoryGirl cannot create user cause it cannot assign its password. Could you add your User model code?

Comment: Ok, you're using Devise. You should add the `password_confirmation` to your  `:user` factory first of all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Devise, you need to add the `password_confirmation` to your `:user` factory